# React scripts access management with Express (React+Node+Express)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I’m new to React, and I have trouble with finding best solution for my app.

My current (Node.js+Express+Handlebars) app has one main menu with place where I render HTML received from AJAX request made after click on menu element. Then all actions inside this element are done by proper JS script. I wanted to improve it by using React, but I have problem with permissions management.

Currently, after authentication, handlebars receive list of files which user should load and render it as src in  element. If user has access to only 5 of 20 modules, he can access only proper JS files. Also, he can’t access HTML he don’t has access to.

How to manage it in React? I want to have one interface for all users, but I don’t want to store logic for all components accessible for every user. I was thinking about something like AJAX loading components for React, but how to manage it?

Is it even possible? As I understand (maybe wrong), all React components are compiled from separated JSX files to one main.js, so is it possible to add separate files with other components?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue that you have encountered is a crucial step on the long stairway of making something great. The solution to your problem is the balance of all the present factors and consolidation of them to cooperate on a mutually beneficial basis. I hope that solves your problem